# I didn't start work on my first day agreed on contract

Tags: new-job, start-date

Last Monday, I went to office to start my new job. A manager received me and spent the whole morning with me. I had a guided tour in the building and whatnot. Then, my contact sent my credentials related to a customer through whatsapp (she called in sick).

The thing is that I haven't received my company's account yet, nor did I get a machine. The manager told me they will contact me for the onboarding and to get my machine as soon as it is ready.

It's been 3 days now, I haven't heard from them at all.

Also, I submitted my contract and documents a couple of weeks ago. They had more than ten days to prepare things for me.

Does this sound normal? Should I remain patient?

Comment: when you say you haven't heard from them, are you going into the office and sitting there alone not working, or are you sitting at home waiting for someone to invite you back to the office?

Comment: How large is the company you joined? Would you say it is a corporate company?

Comment: This isn't abnormal if they need to get a certain number of new starters in the room for booked training

Comment: Is this a work-from-home position, or one where you work from the office? If the latter, have you been to the office every day? Did you get a desk assigned? Is "a" manager your manager?

Comment: The question title seems wrong (or at least, makes an unjustified assumption). It seems likely that you _did_ start work (as I'd understand the term) — even if you didn't start _productive_ work. (But that's not very unusual; I've had jobs where I wasn't productive for the first week or month.) Of course, it probably depends upon the jurisdiction, having a valid contract, etc., but since you are available for work, I expect that legally, you _are_ working for the company.

Comment: I came away from reading this quite confused. More context please.

Answer (score 55):

> Does this sound normal ? Should I remain patient?

I wouldn't say that it is typical, but it does happen.  I used to work for a company where new hires would sometimes go up to a few weeks before they received their equipment, account,...etc.

Patience is the key but it doesn't hurt to follow up to check on the status.  In the meantime, you should ask your manager for any work that you can do while you wait or any documentation that you can go through.  The key is to keep yourself occupied and show that you have interest in working for this company.  It is not a good look if you just sit around doing nothing without even attempting to contribute as an employee.

Comment: I joined like 2 months after accepting the job offer, and it still took 2 weeks until I had all the accounts/logins/access/software I needed. I was told this is fairly typical, not sure why they don't keep a list of all the things a new hire will need (the guy who came two months later had the same story). Keep following up every day or so (or less, depending on the company) and hopefully it will get sorted out soon.

Comment: @Esther Different management sphere and accountability. You may have a different service for each kind of account and setting up hadware/software. Even if it's only one it's KPI are different than the "business" KPI. Having new hire sitting sown for two weeks hurt business but doesn't hurt those in charge of on boarding KPI's so there is no problem. And they may have been refused investment to do things properly as they don't bring "business value"

Comment: @sf02, You must have worked for the same company as I did...

Comment: For an extreme example, there was one engineering house I worked at BITD (GE Aerospace) that mostly did work that required security clearances. These could take several months to get, so there was (I was told) a special building new hires got sent to so they could wait for their clearance to come in. Their only job in the interim was to fill out their end of the clearance paperwork and do whatever (non-classified) training the company might ask for. Supposedly a lot of Spades and Hearts were played.

Comment: @T.E.D. I have an almost-identical story, except it was the mid-2010s and Magic: The Gathering was the card game of choice :P

Comment: @Esther At my company, some forms to request certain accounts can only be filled by the newcomer once they sit at their desk and can log in. This is a constraint of our IT, and as the manager I can't change it. It's frustrating that I can't fully anticipate this when I hire people.

Answer (score 41):

You were available to your employer, so you did start working.

If the employer did not make the necessary preparations to get you to be more productive, that is up to him and his leadership/organization/priorities.

Just make sure that those involved (typically your manager and maybe HR) know that you have issues and that you are available but not doing anything useful due to reasons outside your control.

Make use of your time trying to learn anything you can about your job: technologies, procedures... Maybe offer to "shadow" a more experienced worker to get the most of your time.

Answer (score 17):

As long as you receive your paycheque, all the rest can take time :)

Answer (score 10):

Not at all unusual. I have contracted for *cough* decades in 15 countries on 3 continents and this has cropped up all over.

Normally they stick you in a room with a ton of project documentation to read until IT gets its finger out.

Just make sure to look in on your manager or teammates to say good morning, to establish that you are present & there will be no problems when you come to get your time-sheet signed.

If they told you not to come in, you should have clarified that you will be paid. If not, do so now.

Tell your recruiter that without clarification you are actively seeking employment. Ask them to look for you. That will worry them enough to chase it up. If they can't profit from you there, they will want to be the ones to profit from you elsewhere, so will be highly motivated to find you something before another recruiter does.

If you sit around making no waves, no one is motivated to act. Make them worry a little and things will happen. Don't be afraid to ask; it is perfectly understandable, given the circumstances. No one will be uset with you for asking.

Comment: *If they told you not to come in, you should have clarified that you will be paid* under which circumstances could the OP not have been paid for these days?

Comment: If the company was delaying the start date. Their logic would be "if he can't be productive until IT gets things done, then let's push back his start date"; why pay for no work?". Doesn't mean that it's right or fair, but it's logical to them. Happened to me last September and I lost 3 weeks pay. My contract was with the agency, not the end client - that's contracting. I wasn't going to get legal on the agency; there is always a clause that says that the  contract can be terminated with zero notice in the first month. I did tell them to look for more work & threw my CV at other agencies ... ->

Comment: ... -> but IT finally got its finger out & I am now on a Greenfields project, the best in 20 years. It's all part of life's rich tapestry, and why they pay us the big bucks.

Comment: @WoJ Like the circumstances of any employee expected to come to work who doesn't. With the addition of the fact that they are probably within their trial period. Details will vary a lot depending on the country/state/industry/type of contract, but in many places, if your employer doesn't see you and you don't say anything, at best you won't be paid, at worst you're fired.

Comment: @jcaron: of course if you do not show up you are at fault. But this is snit the case of OP, they are coming and sitting idly (at least this is how I read the question). In that case they are paid as if they were working.

Comment: @WoJ the first comment on the question shows that many people (me including) are wondering what OP actually means. Are they showing up at work every day and just waiting for someone to take care of them, or did they come just the first day and are now waiting at home for something to happen? The latter may be possible and justified if it's actually a work-from-home position, but we haven't received any clarification from OP on those circumstances.